# React props inmmutable vs Props changes in REACT lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle, prop

I have read alot of documentation about REACT JS and I have found in several sites that .props should be inmmutable... If that's so, Why in the React Component Lifecycle the are some functions that are triggered when the props are changed?

http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 1):

Props are passed in from your parent. One way to think of them is like a local variable on a stack, in a programming language. You can change them in your code, but that change is only visible **in the current component**, nowhere else. The next time your parent component renders, those changes will be wiped out.

Re: the React lifecycle, 
you're probably thinking of `componentWillReceiveProps`, which is called when your parent renders. It is fired when **new** props are passed into an **existing** component. They will have the same names as existing props, and they may or may not have new values. You can take action in your local state based on when new props come in. You can use it or ignore it, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

its allowed to change props and makes sense in a lot of cases.
the immutability is not meant as u r not allowed to change the prop.

immutability in this context means u should use https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/ when u have deep objects that will be passed as props. of cause u can change the prop but the lib refered to makes sure u always get a complete new object every time you change someting (because the original is immutable ;) ).

the reason u should use a complete new object when the prop changes is so react actually realizes that the prop was changed, because it internaly does no deep compare but just compares the reference to the object. therefore immutable objects as props are the only way to make sure ur changes will be propagated through ur component tree when u make deep changes in ur passed objects/props.

Answer (score 0):

For react, immutablity means more or less:

> Once you have passed an object to react as props or in state, you
>   should never change that same object. Make a copy into a new
>   object, and change the copy.

React does not have any lifecycle methods that are triggered by a "change in props". React's lifecycle functions will run whenever a higher component passes in a new set of props. Even if the new props are the same as the old props, react will still run all its lifecycle methods.

There are 2 reasons why immutability is important:

1. Whenever you define new props, react compares the new props with the old props, and decides whether it needs to update the DOM. If they are the same, react will NOT update the DOM (even though all lifecycle methods did run).
2. Sometimes you want your own code to compare new props with old props (e.g. to change color or whatever). Some lifecycle methods give you access to both new and old props for that. For your code in there to be reliable, you need to make sure that the props do not change after you pass them to react.

Simplified example when things go right:

```
oldUser = { name: "Bill" }                          // points to object with name Bill
<Component user={oldUser}/>
newUser = Object.assign(oldUser, { name: "Dave" })  // new object
<Component user={newUser}/>

// newUser != oldUser (different objects): 
// react will run render function + update DOM
```

Example where things go wrong:

```
oldUser = { name: "Bill" }  // points to object with name Bill
<Component user={oldUser}/>
newUser = oldUser           // newUser points to the same object as oldUser
newUser.name = "Dave"       // Now also oldUser.name == "Dave"
<Component user={newUser}/>

// newUser == oldUser (same objects + both have name "Dave"): 
// react will run render function, but will NOT update DOM
```